# Making a shell in C, but can't get chdir to work?

Tags: c, linux, shell, command-line, command

I'm writing a shell in C that's supposed implement several commands, one of them being the change directory command. To change directories, I use chdir(), but every time I run my code, I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. 
Here's my code:

```
.....
........
char *shell;
while((shell=readline("shell> ") )){
char *cmd = strtok(shell," ");

if(strcmp(cmd,"ls")==0)
 {
    //do something
 }
 else if(strcmp(cmd,"print")==0)
 {
   //do something
 }
else if(strcmp(cmd,"cd")==0){

            char *directory = strtok(NULL," ");

            if(chdir(directory)==-1){
                printf("Error\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("changed directories!");
            }


        }
      add_history(shell);
 }
```

I think I might be using strtok incorrectly?

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: have you tried adding some debugging output to see at which line it crashes?

Comment: It looks like you're doing a strtok on 'directory' and then using 'dir' for chdir command - is that intentional?

Also, the output in strtok would be "cd" in the first iteration, you need to call strtok again with 'NULL' as string input to get the next delimited string.

Comment: If your program crashes, you should run it in a debugger to catch the crash. That will tell you *where* it crashes, and let you examine the function call stack, and even let you walk up the call stack so you can get to your code (if the debugger doesn't stop there already). When you have located the crash in your code, then you can examine the values of variables to help you figure out what might have caused the crash. If you still can't figure it out, then update your question to tell us the location of the crash, and the values of all involved variables.

Comment: Ok here are the changes I made: 
else if(strcmp(command,"cd")==0){
     
    char *com = strtok(command," ");
    char *dir = strtok(NULL," ");
     
     if(chdir(dir)==-1){
      perror("Error: ");
      //printf("Error:Could not change directories\n");
     }
     else
     {
      printf("Successfully changed directories\n");
     }
    
    
    }

Now, whenever I run it, I get this error: Error: Bad Address. No matter what I pass to it, it says bad addresss. I tried passing .. to it to go one directory up, but that also gave a bad address error

Comment: Add the code to the question.  Don't forget to end output lines with a newline.  You didn't check whether `dir` was null — given the crash, it probably was.  Don't forget, when you type `cd` to go home, there is no space.

Comment: @user3266259 `command` doesn't seem to be in your code. Do you want to tokenize the first token (got from a previous `strtok()`) or parse the next token from `shell`?

Comment: I edited my question so it now has the changes I made to the code, but now I'm getting a bad address error.When I run it, I do the following:
cd somedirectory
or cd .. (to go one directory up)
But it all gives me a bad address error

Comment: @user3266259 Please don't edit to posts to incorporate answer(s). And for your issue, it might be something else (not in the posted code). Or `directory` is NULL. Check the return value of *all* `strtok()` calls for `NULL`.

Comment: A simple way to debug this would be to print `shell` and `cmd` and `directory` strings to see what they have. Most likely `directory` was NULL.

Comment: @l3x, you were right, directory was actually NULL. And when I printed cmd, it had the command name in it (in this case, "cd"). I think I'm still confused on how to properly use strtok() to get it to do what I want it to. From the string "cd /home/usr/documents", I want to store "cd" in cmd, (which is already the case) and "/home/usr/documents" in the directory variable.

Comment: @user3266259 Your usage as is, is fine. I suspect you have *another* strtok() call somewhere in your code between this `char *cmd = strtok(shell," ");` and `char *directory = strtok(NULL," ");` which causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
    char *directory = strtok(cmd," ");
```

should be

```
        char *directory = strtok(NULL," ");
```

When you call `strtok()` to get the next token, you pass `NULL` to it.

Moreover, `strtok()` is not re-entrant. So you can't use it even if your plan was to tokenize a different string. You can use [`strtok_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) on POSIX systems.